# Tags showing when i use TinyMCE to post new Paragraph

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, tags

i'm using TinyMCE to post new Paragraph to the website

and after posting its showing the Paragraph like this:

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

so its posting the tags as well

how to solve this problem?

-This is how i'm printing the paragraph:

```
<p> {{$data->subtitle}} </p>
```

Comment: Please show the code how you are printing the paragraph :)

Comment: @JoelPeltonen i have added it to the post

Comment: Looks like you wrapping "Some text" in <p> tag, while it is already exists in the subtitle. Or is it that your <p> tag is visible along with the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by decode the string:

```
<?php
  $str = $data->subtitle;
  echo html_entity_decode($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code you are not just using regular old PHP, but rather something like a Larvel Blade template.

Often templating systems don't allow you to output HTML like that directly due to security reasons (they are trying to prevent injection attacks, you should be aware of them!!).

If it is indeed Blade, try doing

```
{!! $data->subtitle !!}
```

- Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data
- Also read: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-data